# Linker Error cutest binary with matlab

Tags: c++, linux, matlab, fortran, gfortran

I need to implement a library with mathematical problems to test an algorithm I wrote in matlab. The library is called "cutest" (see here: http://ccpforge.cse.rl.ac.uk/gf/project/cutest/wiki/).

As I am using Ubuntu, it's not possible to install this thing via the homebrew repo. Therefore I was doing the manual installation and was able to install cutest and the problemdecoder "sifdec" (also downloadable ob the page above).

I am now stuck in the point, where I need to compile a binaryfile that can be used by matlab. I guess it has something to do with the compiler flags of fortran/gcc and a 32/64 bit thing (as I was already scrolling through other posts and google).

The Error I get is the following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `/home/beck/CUTEst/cutest
/objects/pc64.lnx.gfo/double/mcutest.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 
output
/usr/bin/ld: /home/beck/CUTEst/cutest/objects/pc64.lnx.gfo/double
/mcutest.o: file class ELFCLASS32 incompatible with ELFCLASS64
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

mex: link of ' "mcutest.mexa64"' failed.
```

The mex file is from matlab, I didn't modify it yet (nor the optionsfile for mex).

The settings for the makefile "pc64.lnx.gfo", which I created (automatically) via a terminal installation are the following:

```
#  Architecture dependent makefile
#  (automatically generated by install_cutest)

VERSION = pc64.lnx.gfo

#  Basic system commands

CP = /bin/cp
MV = /bin/mv
RM = /bin/rm -f
SED = /bin/sed
GREP = /bin/grep
AR = /usr/bin/ar
RANLIB = /usr/bin/ranlib

#  Directory for binaries

PRECIS = double
OBJ = $(CUTEST)/objects/$(VERSION)/$(PRECIS)
OBJS = $(CUTEST)/objects/$(VERSION)/single
OBJD = $(CUTEST)/objects/$(VERSION)/double
MOD = $(CUTEST)/modules/$(VERSION)/$(PRECIS)
SEDS = $(CUTEST)/seds/$(PRECIS).sed
MVMODS = $(MV) -f $(OBJ)/*.mod $(MOD)/ || true

#  Compiler options

FORTRAN = gfortran-4.7
BASIC = -c -fno-second-underscore -fPIC
MODULES =  -I$(MOD)
OPTIMIZATION = -O
NOOPTIMIZATION = -O0
DEBUG = 
OPENMP = -fopenmp
F77 = -ffixed-form
F90 = 
F95 = 
NOFMAIN = 
USUAL = 
SPECIAL = 
F77SUFFIX = f90
F95SUFFIX  = f90
TIMER = GEN
NOT95 = IS95
NOT64 = IS64

AMPLDIR   = 
CC        = gcc-4.7
CCBASIC   = -c -ansi -pedantic -fPIC
CCONDEF   = 
CCDEBUG   = 
CCFFLAGS  = -lgfortran

#  Special flags


#  Libraries

BLAS = 
LAPACK = 
CUTESTUSED = 

#  Shell used

BINSHELL = sh

#  Set directories for optional packages

include $(CUTEST)/src/makedefs/packages

#  Body of makefile

include $(PWD)/makemaster
```

I'd really appreciate any kind of help, this issue keeps me from going further with my master thesis.

EDIT: Added outputs of gcc-4.7/gfortran-4.7 -v

gcc-4.7 -v:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc-4.7
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.4-3ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc --with-cloog --enable-cloog-backend=ppl --disable-cloog-version-check --disable-ppl-version-check --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.4 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.4-3ubuntu3)
```

gfortran-4.7 -v:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran-4.7
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.4-3ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc --with-cloog --enable-cloog-backend=ppl --disable-cloog-version-check --disable-ppl-version-check --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.4 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.4-3ubuntu3)
```

Comment: Are there any other lines in the output preceding the error? In particular, the flags of gfortran would be useful.

Comment: There's nothing more but a warining from matlab about the support of mex files in general (they will be removed in further versions).

The compiler flags of fortran are inside the codebox I posted, directly after "#  Compiler options" up to "NOT64=IS64". The flags after that are from the gcc compiler. I've tried out some things like an -m32 or -m64 flag but nothing worked so far. Still I think it has something to do with that.

Comment: The `cutest.o` "library" that you are attempting to link is a 32-bit object
file (not actually a *library*). You're trying to link it with a 64-bit binary. 
That won't work. Is it the case then that you don't understand why you have built a 32-bit `cutest.o` and want to build a 64-bit one? If so, please post the details of the compiler(s) you used to build `cutest.o` as output by `gcc -v`, `gfortran -v`, and the exact sequence of steps by which you built your `cutest.o`.

Comment: As I never worked with compilers before I think I want to build a 64-bit cutest.o yes. The gcc -v and gfortran -v are 5.2.1, but I'm 99% sure I used 4.7 cause of matlab (never versions are not supported, see here: [link](http://de.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015b/index.html?sec=glnxa64&refresh=true) and 4.7 is as well installed.
The built of cutest.o is done by the cutest environment. Apart from the installation parameters I just enter `cutest2matlab problem.SIF` for an example problem. I can post the installation choices but the important choices are the ones above in the box I guess.

Comment: According to the partial makefile you've posted the compilers used were
`gcc-4.7` and `gfortran-4.7`. I want the outputs of `gcc-4.7/gfortran-4.7 -v`,
not the outputs of `gcc-4.7/gfortran-4.7 --version`. Please include this information in the question.

Comment: Oh damn me, I missunderstood that. As the outputs are too long for a comment I'll edit my question and paste them there.

Comment: You should always put relevant information in the question. Your compilers are 64-bit compilers, so that is not the problem. What release and architecture (x86, x86_64|amd64) of matlab do you have?

Comment: I'm running the newest version, R2015b, on 64-bit which can also be confirmed by the .mexa64 ending. Is there even a x86_64 release? Didn't find one so I think we can assume it's x86.

Comment: `x86` name-components conventionally denote 32-bit binaries; `x86_64|amd64` denotes 64-bit. Either can be installed and run on a 64-bit OS but can only be linked with their own kind. A 64-bit compiler produces 64-bit binaries by default but can be directed to produce 32-bit. It appears likely that your toolchain is 64-bit
throughout. Nevertheless your build is generating a 32-bit object file and
failing to link it in a 64-bit binary. To fully reproduce your build I would need to buy and install your version of matlab (for which I have no personal use), so I'm afraid I can get no further.

Comment: As I own an academic license and only take use of the mex files which are as well supported in older versions I could install an older one (which one do you own/are you able to test with?). My algorithm code to solve converted problems should work on pretty much every version.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I have no use for matlab, so have no version of it.
If you add further info to your question, namely the command you typed
from which the linkage error ensues and the complete console output of
that command, I or someone else might be able to see where the 32-bit-ness is coming from. If you capture it by redirecting to a file be sure to redirect errors as well as standard output, i.e. `command > file 2>&1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with the help of an academic member of my university. In case anyone has/will have the same problem here is what worked for me:

As the toolchain was 64-bit and the only file that was generated in 32-bit was the `mcutest.o` the error had to be in combination with the mex compilation (cause only this file was compiled with the mex compiler of matlab).

Inside the folderstructure was a file called `makemaster` which holds the settings alredy choosen in the installation progress for gfortran and gcc, but also settings for mex (which i wasn't asked to modify yet). However, after some testing, adding the line `CFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)'` in the `MFLAGS` resulted in a 64-bit output file and the error didn't occur anymore.

Thanks for your help anyway!